# descargar archivos desde Putty

Tags: git-bash, putty

Necesito hacer un volcado de una lista que he sacado por el putty desde el putty si me pudierais ayudar

Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con volcado? ¿A coger el texto y guardarlo en un editor de texto?

Comment: si ayer ya logre hacer un volcado pero no de esa manera, me lo guardare para proximas veces gracias

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, ayuda a la comunidad agregando lo que has tratado o investigado por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que usar el `scp`; la gente del putty lo hace y lo tenes que usar desde la `terminal de windows`.

Ejemplo:

```
scp ubnt@192.168.66.1:/tmp/tanaza-unifi-x.y.z.bin c:\
```